# What's the difference between Gray box and Black box testing?

Tags: manual

I m trying to understand one in terms of how it compares to the other.

Is grey box testing where you can see the code and black box testing where you don't look at the code?

Answer (score 1):

Black box testing is when you know nothing about the system. You know the input and you check the output without knowing anything about the process in between input and output.

Grey box testing is almost the same but you know some things about the internals of the system. For example you have knowledge about the architecture or you have some implementation documents. It is actually a mix of white (see further) and black box testing (it's in between).

White box testing is when you know everything about the system. Source code, architecture. You test the program completely, check if it is doing what is expected, check for exceptions or errors. For this you have to really understand how the code works.

So to answer your question, with both black box and grey box testing you don't really check the code. In grey box testing it's more about the internal structure and architecture you have knowledge, sometimes in some algorithms used.

You can find info on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_box_testing) or [this url](http://www.careerride.com/Testing-white-box-black-box-gray-box.aspx) that explains white, grey and black box testing.

Answer (score 0):

gray is where you have some hints on the system you're testing not the source code though.eg if you knew what CMS and version the site is running,what server side lanuage it implemented php,.Net,Java.The latter one is where you have no prior information like what OS it's running on,with what programming language its written about the system you're testing and you're given just the target.

Comment: Can you provide detail description for the same ?